# Polymer not initializing Fabric.js on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, polymer, fabricjs, web-component

I am trying to create a free drawing canvas using WebComponent, Polymer to be more precise. I have created a component, and the code is:

```
<polymer-element name="video-canvas" attributes="pad sourceVideo widthVideo heightVideo preloadVideo">
  <template>
   <div id= "content-container" >
    <div class="canvas-container" >
        <canvas id="c" height={{canvasHeight}} width={{canvasWidth}} style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);  left: 10px; top: 10px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: crosshair;"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
    <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
                }   
            #video{
            margin-left: {{videoMargin}}px;
            margin-top:{{canvasMarginTop}}px;
            }
    </style>

  </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('video-canvas',{
        width: '320',
        height: '240',
        src:'http://golovin.de/ba/parking.mp4',
        padding:'3',
        canvas:null,
        domReady: function() {
        this.canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
            isDrawingMode: true
        });
            this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10,
            this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#FF0000',
            console.log(this.canvas)
        }

        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This is the video-canvas.html component.
The index file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video Canvas</title>
    <!-- Importing Web Component's Polyfill -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Importing Custom Elements -->
    <link rel="import" href="video-canvas.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Using Custom Elements -->
    <video-canvas id = "videoCanvas" pad="100" sourceVideo="http://golovin.de/ba/parking.mp4"  widthVideo="640" heightVideo="300" preloadVideo="auto"></video-canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that in Firefox 36.0.1 it works perfectly fine, but in Google Chrome 41.0.2272.101 it just does not work. I can see that the Fabric.js canvas is not initialized properly. I am sure there should be some stupid mistake of mine, but cannot figure it out. Or could it be some problem of Fabric.js?

Comment: The code you have provided won’t run in FF. You are setting your component’s attributes `src` and `sourceVideo` which in fact does nothing. There is no one control able to play video. In your polymer init code you have syntax errors (commas after last two assignments instead of semicolons. This code would never run under any circumstances. Downvote.

Comment: The attributes are there for other purposes, which are irrelevant for the problem that I have. The point is not to play the video, the point is to be able to draw on the canvas. According to the syntax it runs perfectly fine, because i can already use it myself on Firefox.

Comment: You have provided a bundle of irrelevant code, having syntax errors (despite that FF tolerates them, what in fact is a FF problem.) There is no one line trying to draw on canvas. So, what your question is? Why does this code, which generally should not work, work in FF?

Comment: https://github.com/rwth-acis/sevianno-video-canvas
This is the github repository. The code is not irrelevant. Even that i fixed the problem of comas and semicolons. You can check it your self if you don't believe. FabricJs is a HTML5 canvas tool (www.fabricjs.com). The instructions at domReady: enable the user to draw on the canvas (free drawing). My question is why does this not work on Google Chrome. To my opinion there is a problem with FabricJS and Polymer. I was hoping for an answer from somebody that might have an idea about this, not somebody to correct syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when i changed this line:

```
this.canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
            isDrawingMode: true
        });
```

to:

```
this.canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.$.c, {
            isDrawingMode: true
        });
```

Now it works perfectly fine.